# Why Qualcomm 9205 iot modem drop data network connection before enter PSM mode?

Tags: mqtt, iot, aws-iot, qualcomm

I was under the impression that in NB IoT world, if the client device enters PSM mode, it can actually retain both the IOT network registration and also the TCP IP connection session. so when it wake up from PSM, it can quickly send data and go back to sleep again. but in my case, it imitates disconnection of the PDP session before it enter PSM.  Is this normal ??

Currently I am using a dev client system based on Qualcomm 9205 modem connect to LTE Cat-M1 network.

the client will wake up every 10min to send a small chunk of data (100byte) to the AWS IOT service, it uses MQTT as the messaging protocol .

ideally I prefer the device to initiate the MQTT connection with the server once, then after it goes to PSM sleep, the client side remembers the MQTT connection, so when it wake up, it can just send the data via MQTT without re-establish the MQTT connection again.

Unfortunately, I realise the real behaviour is: when I ask the modem to go to PSM sleep, it will drop the PDP connection (which means the TCP/IP session is lost, so does MQTT ), so when it wake up, it will take extra 5-10 seconds also to re-establish MQTT connection again before sending data. this is a waste of both time and additional data communication.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Justin, any update on this? I'm testing Quectel BC66 and SIM7020 and both also don't like to entering PSM while a TCP socket is open. Actually on BC66 the network disconnection happens but the module doesn't go into low power, as if the module RTOS keeps on running.